# Mysql import command working when running on cmd but not when passing arguments directly

Tags: mysql, command-line, cmd

As I follow from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html), The import command in its most basic form is:

```
mysql.exe < example.sql
```

It works when I run it from the command line in Windows. But it doesn't work when I start the process `mysql.exe` with `< example.sql` parameters. For example, creating a shortcut and setting its path to `mysql.exe < example.sql` doesn't work and it only prints the help info for `mysql.exe`.

As a side note, I first noticed this problem when trying to run the following C# code:

```
new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "mysql.exe",
                Arguments = "< example.sql",
            }
        }.Start();
```

Comment: what did you mean by  this mysql.exe with < example.sql parameters

Comment: `< example.sql` are not parameters for `mysql.exe`, the `<` denotes a redirection operator, so the content of file `example.sql` is redirected into `mysql.exe`; I guess you have to change the file name to `cmd.exe` and the arguments to `/C "mysql.exe < example.sql"`; consider to specify full absolute paths to all of the files...

Comment: @aschipfl Do you know a way to pass the sql file as parameter to `mysql.exe`. Also you can turn your comment into answer. It answers my question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you with `mysql.exe`. Just wait a minute to get my comment converted to an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `< example.sql` does not contitute parameters for `mysql.exe`; the `<` character denotes a [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) operator, so the content of file `example.sql` is redirected into `mysql.exe`.

I guess you have to change the file name to `cmd.exe` and the arguments to `/C "mysql.exe < example.sql"`. Consider to specify full absolute paths to all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in windows but I assume you best fill in the full path + database hostname information:

```
C:\mysql\directory\bin\mysql -h {hostname} -u {username} -p {databasename} < example.sql
```

Comment: ...and also the full path to `example.sql`; each path quoted to avoid trouble with white-spaces and other special characters...